# Удаление маршрута eigrp

Tags: маршрутизация, cisco, cisco-ios

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, как удалить маршрут с eigrp? Реализовано было так :

```
ip routing
router eigrp 101
network 10.25.192.0 0.0.0.63
network 10.25.81.0 0.0.0.255
network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255  
exit
```

По началу меня все устраивало, но теперь концепция и требования поменялись, теперь мне нужно **`network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255`** убрать, что бы этой сети не было видно из этих двух

```
network 10.25.192.0 0.0.0.63
network 10.25.81.0 0.0.0.255
```

но она **`network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255`** видела **`network 10.25.81.0 0.0.0.255`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день.
Ну если тупо удалить не анализируя что и зачем то: 
`ROUTER(config)#router eigrp 101
 ROUTER(config-router) no network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255` 
Я хоть и не вижу всей топологии сети, но мне кажется тогда эта сеть станет недоступна, и, как следствие, из неё не будет доступна сеть `10.25.81.0/24`
Сделать видимой `10.25.81.0/24` из `192.168.1.0/24` думаю можно с помощью PBR или статического маршрута. Не видя карты сети сложно дать точный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решен, **ROUTER(config-router) no network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255** вполне устраивает